# Apache lucene indexing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene

I am creating a text search application for log files using apache lucene. I am using the bellow code to index the files

```
doc.add(new LongField("modified", file.lastModified(), Field.Store.NO));
doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"))));
doc.add(new StoredField("filename", file.getCanonicalPath()));
```

Here i am creating 3 indexes for each file But when searching i can retrieve the value of only one index other two come as null. This is the search side code

```
Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
System.out.println(i+":File name is"+d.get("filename"));
System.out.println(i+":File name is"+d.get("modified"));
System.out.println(i+":File name is"+d.get("contents"));
```

The output I am getting is

```
2 total matching documents
0:File name is/home/maclean/NetBeansProjects/LogSearchEngine/src/SimpleSearcher.java
0:File name isnull
0:File name isnull
1:File name is/home/maclean/NetBeansProjects/LogSearchEngine/src/SimpleFileIndexer.java
1:File name isnull
1:File name isnull
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: use Field.Store.YES instead of Field.Store.NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lucene, if you want to retrieve the value for a field, you need to store that field. If a field is not stored, on searching its value will be `null`.

For `modified`, you've explicitly specified it as a un-stored field by passing the argument `Field.Store.NO`; as a result it's value is **not** being stored in the index and hence, null is returned on search. To store and retrieve its value, you need to change the constructor call to:

```
doc.add(new LongField("modified", file.lastModified(), Field.Store.YES));
```

For `contents`, the constructor you've used creates un-stored field. You need to change its constructor to:

```
doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8")), Field.Store.YES));
```

After these changes, you should be able to retrieve both the fields.

You are able to retrieve values for `filename` because you are using a constructor that creates stored fields by default.